# Unable to access cellvalue when using external filter ag-grid with angularjs

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I'm using an external filter in ag-grid which is supposed to filter the records based on a select value dropdown which has values corresponding to a specific field in the grid.

And I'm unable to access the value of the field using node.data.fieldName as mentioned in the documentation [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filter-external/).

Below is what I'm doing:

```
function isExternalFilterPresent() {

                    return $scope.filterval.ReleaseType!='All' && $scope.filterval.ReleaseType!='';
                }
                function doesExternalFilterPass(){
                    console.log('$scope.filterval.ReleaseType : ' ,$scope.filterval.ReleaseType);
                    if($scope.filterval.ReleaseType == 'A'){return node.data.ReleaseType = 'A';}
                    if($scope.filterval.ReleaseType == 'B'){}
                    if($scope.filterval.ReleaseType == 'C'){}
                    if($scope.filterval.ReleaseType == 'D'){}
                    if($scope.filterval.ReleaseType == 'D'){}
                }
```

It throws an error : node is not defined
When I try using just data.fieldName it says 'data is not defined'

Can someone please help me understand how I can access the value of the specific field here.

Comment: reproduce your issue on plunk or stackblitz. By just looking at two functions I can obviously say that `node` further `node.data` is not defined anywhere - hence, you are getting the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide `node` as an argument to the function. [ag-grid](/questions/tagged/ag-grid) calls this function with appropriate argument `node`.

> Link: [Example External filter](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filter-external/#example-external-filter)

```
     function doesExternalFilterPass(node) {   // <- node as argument
       console.log('$scope.filterval.ReleaseType : ' ,$scope.filterval.ReleaseType);
       if($scope.filterval.ReleaseType == 'A'){return node.data.ReleaseType = 'A';}
           if($scope.filterval.ReleaseType == 'B'){}
             if($scope.filterval.ReleaseType == 'C'){}
             if($scope.filterval.ReleaseType == 'D'){}
             if($scope.filterval.ReleaseType == 'D'){}
       }
```